# How do I setup an OpenShift route that will allow both 80 and 443 traffic to my app?

Tags: security, networking, openshift, encryption

I'd like to setup a route that will pass both 80 and 443 traffic to the same service in OpenShift. When I try to create a second route it errors out. I want this to be in a yaml like would be used with `oc create -f route.yaml` so I can submit it to our IaC code repo.

Comment: Could you add the logging?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to be sure your spec.tls section has the following two items to tell the router you want both secure and insecure traffic allowed in the edge.

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: my-app-ui
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  host: my-host
  port:
    targetPort: http
  tls:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Allow
    termination: edge
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-app-ui
    weight: 100
  wildcardPolicy: None
```